# Struct ordering and stack smashing in C

Tags: c, struct

I have created a struct in C containing the data from a group of students and I want to order that information considering the first letter of their names. My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int cod;
    char* name;
    int grade;
}student;

void print(student* classroom){
     int i;
     for (i=0;i<4;i++){
         printf("%d\n",classroom[i].cod);
         printf("%s\n",classroom[i].name);
         printf("%d\n",classroom[i].grade);
         printf("\n");
     }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int ind,i;
  int cod=1000;
  student classroom[4];
  student temp;
  int tam_cad=10;
  for (i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
         classroom[i].name=malloc(sizeof(char)*tam_cad);
  }
  classroom[0].cod=cod;
  classroom[0].name="George";
  classroom[0].grade=5;
  cod++;
  classroom[1].cod=cod;
  classroom[1].name="Bob";
  classroom[1].grade=6;
  cod++;
  classroom[2].cod=cod;
  classroom[2].name="Karen";
  classroom[2].grade=7;
  cod++;
  classroom[3].cod=cod;
  classroom[3].name="Anna";
  classroom[3].grade=10;
  print(classroom);

  for (ind=1;ind<4;ind++){
      temp=classroom[ind];
      i=ind-1;
      while (i>=0){
            if (temp.name[0]<classroom[i].name[0]){
                classroom[i+1]=classroom[i];
                classroom[i]=temp;
                i--;
           }
           else break;
      }
  }
  print(classroom);

  return 0;
}
```

I am using the insertion sort algorithm, but when I compile it the program runs and the following message appears:

```
1003
Anna
10

1001
Bob
6

1000
George
5

1002
Karen
7

*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted
```

It looks that is ordering the data (I am using an online compiler), but when I use CodeBlocks with C the program does not shows any answer. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: There is no classroom index 3 in your classroom array of size 3.

Comment: You also have memory leaks all over, assingning a string literal to `name` member after you allocated memory for it.

Comment: @Little You made it worse. Now in the loop you also access index `3` of the array, when it only has index `0` to `2`, inclusive.

Comment: thanks @anastaciu, how can I fix that?

Comment: Please don't fix your question as you get more input.

Comment: you have to make sure that `classroom[i+1]` doesn't access out of bound

Comment: your code runs fine for me - as other have pointed out you do not need that malloc loop